# Interrupting idle thread pool workers

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have an application that starts a JUnit test run with some tests that create a few fixed-size thread pools without shutting them down afterwards. This leaves idle thread pool workers that I need to get rid of. I do not have control of the test code, only the code that starts the test run. Is there any way at all (safe or unsafe) that I can force the worker threads to shut down?

My current, non-working, solution attempt looks like this:

```
Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for (Thread thread: threads) {
    if (thread.getName().matches("pool-\\d+-thread-\\d+")) {
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I would like a solution where I can still run the tests in the same JVM. Spawning a separate process is the last resort at this point.

Edit: I do not have any way to get a reference to the ExecutorService that spawned the worker threads (they are created in the test code which I do not have control over).

Comment: Threads need to have a policy of some kind to get them to shut down. Interrupting != shutdown necessarily. The best thing to do is search the docs for whatever creates the threads and see what its shutdown policy is, e.g. call a destroy or shutdown method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to start the threads, then you can use `shutdownNow` followed by `awaitTermination`. The linked javadocs contain example code for an orderly shutdown.

Comment: This does not help me, since I have no reference to the ExecutorService.

Comment: ExecutorService reference = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Comment: @Warkst Yep, that's pretty much what the test case does, but I can not access the reference outside the test, and I can not edit the test.

Comment: Who wrote the tests? Good test code cleans up after itself, so whoever wrote it should implement code to terminate any threads they created.